# How to create a Many to Many association in sequelize and nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a many to many relationship between user table and role table through userroles table.
After table creation the db looks just fine, I tried pretty much everything I found on the sequelize documentation and previous answers here, nothing seems to work.

I am getting this error: EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: UserRoles is not associated to User!

Any idea of what am I doing wrong ? please help!

```
class User extends Model {
    
    static associate(models) {
      User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
        foreignKey: "user_id",
        through:'UserRoles',
        as:"users"
      });
      
     
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },

      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      phone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );
```

```
class Role extends Model {
    
    static associate(models) {
      Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        foreignKey: "role_id",
        through:'UserRoles',
         as:"roles"    
      });
     
    }
  }
  Role.init(
    {
      role_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique:true
      },
      role_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      role_desc: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Role",
    }
  );
```

```
 class UserRoles extends Model {
   
    static associate(models) {
     
    }
  }
  UserRoles.init(
    {
      userroles_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      // user_id: {
      //   type: DataTypes.UUID,
      //   defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,

      // },
      // role_id: {
      //   type: DataTypes.UUID,
      //   defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,

      // },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "UserRoles",
    }
  );
```

```
const signup = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log("signup entry");
  if (
    !req.body.role ||
    !req.body.email ||
    !req.body.password ||
    !req.body.name ||
    !req.body.phone
  ) {
    res.status(400).send({
      msg: "Please pass role, email, password and name.",
    });
  } else {
    sequelize.models.User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: req.body.email,
      },
    })
      .then((duplicateemailfound) => {
        if (duplicateemailfound) {
          console.log(duplicateemailfound);
          return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Email already registered",
          });
        } else {
          let userRole = req.body.role.toLowerCase();
          console.log("userRole:", userRole);
          sequelize.models.Role.findOne({
            where: {
              role_name: userRole,
            },
          })
            .then((foundRole) => {
              // console.log(foundRole);
              if (foundRole == null) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                  success: false,
                  role: "null or not found",
                });
              }
              // console.log("foundRole", foundRole); // .role_id
              let addUser = {
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password,
                name: req.body.name,
                phone: req.body.phone,
                role_id: foundRole.role_id,
              };

              sequelize.models.User.create(addUser, {
                include: [{ model: sequelize.models.UserRoles }],
              })

                .then((newUser) => {
                  console.log("new user", newUser);
                  return res.status(201).json({
                    success: true,
                    newuser: newUser,
                  });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                  res.status(400).json({
                    success: false,
                    //   message: "Duplicate Email was Found",
                    error: error.errors[0].message,
                    error: error,
                  });
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              res.status(400).json({
                error: error,
                msg: "bbb",
              });
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: Link to images related to the question above
https://imgur.com/a/YrYXdPU

Comment: You are able to edit your question and add the related images

Answer (score 0):

You create some a class for each Model and extend them with `Model` class of sequelize, this if fine.
Now, you define a `static` method inside the class named `associate(model)` where you define the rule for that class. This is fine because you used `static` which is required here to since it will be a property of the class, not of an object.

Then you call the `initialize` method (a in-built method of class `Model`). In the same way you need to call your defined `associate`.

Here is a problem, because in the structure that you have now, you can't call that method in it's own class file, becuase you need the other Model to pass it as parameter.

So there are 2 solutions:

1. Import your `User` model inside `Role` model file and call the static method, like this:

```
const User = require('User')
class Role extends Model {
    
    static associate(model) {
      Role.belongsToMany(model, {
        foreignKey: "role_id",
        through:'UserRoles',
         as:"roles"    
      });
     
    }
  }
  Role.init(
    {
      role_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique:true
      },
      role_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      role_desc: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Role",
    }
  );
  Role.associate(User);
```

This will use your `User` model to pass it to the static method and finally to run the `belongsToMany`

2. Second solution would be to create an index file for your Models, where you import both of them and you can simply run that `belongsToMany` there, and then simply import that index file in the main file of your application, something like this:

User.js

```
const index = require('./../index.js');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Model = Sequelize.Model;
const sequelize = index.sequelize;

class User extends Model{}

User.init({
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    role: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
},{
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'user'
});



module.exports = {

    User: User
    
}
```

Role.js will look the same but with your own model.
and `index.js` would look like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USERNAME, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT
});

exports.sequelize = sequelize;

const user = require('./models/User');
const role= require('./models/Role');

role.belongsToMany(user, {
        foreignKey: "role_id",
        through:'UserRoles',
         as:"roles"    
      });

sequelize.sync(user);
sequelize.sync(role);

exports.db = {
    user: user,
    role: role
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however as you can see above.. that is exactly what I have been trying to do without success.

Comment: Do you call anywhere that static `associate` method?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by saying "Do you call anywhere that static associate method?"

Comment: You have declared this `static associate(model)` method. This method will not be executed unless you call it. So your `belongToMany` function is not executed unless you call that method

Comment: :o whaaaaaat! ... umm then how table userroles has fk based on the association ?

Comment: Let me update the response

Comment: Thank you Alexandru for this explanation I am not sure however I believe the object.keys method is doing what you are asking for isn't it ?

can you check these screenshots  https://imgur.com/a/iSfehJ1

Comment: Oh, I saw it now. It looks fine at first sigh, but it's a strange approach. Maybe you can run it in debug mode and make sure those commands are running properly or at least consoel.log some values there.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the include property that I am calling inside the signup function ?

Comment: As for the approach this file is auto generated via sequelize-cli

Comment: I ran the debug, here is the output

https://imgur.com/a/50HDmeH

Comment: update: I managed to do what I wanted by modifying my code as shown:
.then(async (newUser) => {
                  let userrolesdata = {
                    user_id: newUser.user_id,
                    role_id: foundRole.role_id,
                  };
                  await sequelize.models.UsersRoles.create(userrolesdata, {})
                    .then((res) => {
                      console.log(res);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      console.log(err);
                    });

It is not automatic as I have hoped but it works..